# 初めてのPython第３版 xiiiページ 理解しにくい説明がある。

Tags: python

初めてのPython第3版 xiiページの「VI部クラスとオブジェクト指向プログラミング」という小見出しの説明文に対する質問です。以下、実際の説明文の抜粋です。

> VI部 クラスとオブジェクト指向プログラミング
>
> VI部では、オブジェクト指向プログラミング(OOP)のツールである「クラス」について学びます。 
>   クラスは、Pythonに必須の要素ではありませんが、クラスを上手く使えば、既存のコードのカスタマイズ、再利用などが容易になります。詳しくは本文で触れますが、PythonのOOP(クラス)で最も重要なことは、
>
> **「オブジェクトのツリーから自動的に適切な属性が検索される」**
>
> ということです。

この「オブジェクトツリーから自動的に適切な属性が検索される」という意味がいまいち理解できません。初学者の自分にわかるように説明してくださると嬉しいです。ちなみに自分はPythonをprogateで一通り学んだ程度で変数や文字列、関数やクラスの概要は大体理解できています。

Comment: VI部を通して読んだけれど、この部分の意味はわからなかった、ということでしょうか?

Comment: いや、まだ VI部は読んでいません。VI部を読めば理解できますか?

Comment: @左翔太朗 本文に「詳しくは本文で触れますが」と書いてあるので、ひとまずその「詳しくは」の部分を読んで頂いて、それでも理解できなければそのことを質問文に追記して頂けませんでしょうか。というのも、このままだと『初めてのPython』に書かれているのであろう詳細な説明と同じことを回答欄に書くことになってしまうと思うからです。章のはじめにある要約文を一読しただけでは意味が分からないということ自体は、良くあることだと思います。

Comment: なるほど分かりました。とりあえずVI部を読んでからもう一度考えてみようと思います。とても丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！